# Executing Multiple Ajax calls at same time while making all but one wait

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have a page that is making several ajax calls at the same time. Each ajax call pertains to a block/div with data that was retrived, for instance, lets say there are 5 divs. When the page is rendered, I want one of the main divs to load entirely and display before the other divs/blocks.

Ex. I have a page that has general info at top, and the other divs are more details on a part of the main div. So they should all be called at the same time, but I want the general div to load all of its content first before allowing the more specific divs display on the screen.

I want all the calls to be asynchronous, but somehow delay the appearance of the others. Is this possible?

I understand that async: false will only delay when the ajax calls are called, but I need them to all be called at the same time.

Any ideas? Please and thank you.

Comment: Load the first one, then use differed execution? https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout(foo, 3000); if you need to wait for a specific time interval then call your function foo() to do what you want after that time interval

Answer (score 0):

You can place/call other Ajax calls on success of general div Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it via angular, on my case I need to query all status before executing to other process. Make a array which combines all of your ajax requests then use `$q.all` equivalent to native javascript's `Promise.all()`

```
   getAllStatusResult() {

      let promises = [];
      let statusList = ['all','done','ongoing','cancelled'];
      let responseList = [];
      let date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
      let deferred = $q.defer();

      statusList.map(status => {
        let payload = {
          start_date: "2017-1-1",
          end_date: formatDate(date),
          filter: { status }          
        }
        promises.push(ReportsService.getRevenues(payload).then((response) => {
          responseList.push({ name: status, total:response.data.total});
        }));
      });


      $q.all(promises).then(() => {
        deferred.resolve(responseList);

      }).then(response => {
        return response;
      });
      return deferred.promise;

   }
```